# C++ Initialize struct with mutex field

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct, syntax, mutex

I'm trying to figure out how to initialize a struct with a mutex field, since the mutex type is not copyable or movable in C++.

I have the struct:

```
typedef struct sample {
  int field1;
  std::mutex mtx;
} sample_t;
```

I'm trying to initialize it in the following way, but I keep getting error: use of deleted function. I'm not super familiar with C++ and would love some help!

```
sample_t* new_sample;
std::mutex a_mtx;
// new_sample->mtx = std::move(a_mtx); (I tried this too)
new_sample->mtx = a_mtx;
new_sample->mtx.lock();
new_sample->field1 = 2;
new_sample->mtx.unlock();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why do you think you need to copy one default-created mutex's value to another default-created mutex? What do you think that does? Do you think `mutex1=mutex2;` somehow makes any thread that held `mutex2` now hold `mutex1`?

Comment: It doesn't need to be initialized at all. You already have a fully constructed instance of std::mutex. You can get rid of `a_mtx`, and just go ahead and call `lock()`.

Comment: When I got rid of ```a_mtx```, I would segfault at the line ```new_sample->mtx.lock()```. If I printed out new_sample in gdb, it looked like ```$1 = (new_sample *) 0x0``` so I thought I would need to initialize it?

Comment: @MaryMatthews You need to initialize `sample_t` object, not it's member. Your pointer is pointing to nowhere.

Comment: The segfault is because `new_sample` is an uninitialized pointer. You can use `sample_t* new_sample = new sample_t;` or don't use a pointer at all: `sample_t new_sample;`

Comment: Unrelated: consider using curly braces to establish a block of code and [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) to manage the mutex. `{const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(new_sample->mtx); new_sample->field1 = 2;}` When the program exits the block for any reason the mutex will be unlocked for you. Not so important here, but as the code between the lock and unlock get more complicated, the odds of an unforeseen exit before the unlock (or simply forgetting to unlock) go up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutex is not copyable and not moveable. But you don't need either of these operatons, you only need to create `sample_t` object - `std::mutex` inside will be initilized by the compiler.

```
sample_t new_sample;

new_sample.mtx.lock();
new_sample.field1 = 2;
new_sample.mtx.unlock();
```

Or, if you really need a pointer for some reason :

```
// sample_t* new_sample = new sample_t;
// you should prefer smart pointers over raw pointers
std::unique_ptr<sample_t> new_sample = std::make_unique<sample_t>();

new_sample->mtx.lock();
new_sample->field1 = 2;
new_sample->mtx.unlock();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JarMan pointed out in a comment, in C++ all of a struct's fields are initialized when the struct is created. The error you are getting about "use of deleted function" is telling you that, once the struct exists, you can't just copy over the mutex which is already there.

However, you do need to actually create the struct; the code you have makes a pointer but doesn't create the struct itself. So you probably want:

```
sample_t* new_sample = new sample_t;
new_sample->mtx.lock();
// ... etc
```

Also, note, in C++ you don't have to do the `typedef` when declaring structs; you can just do

```
struct sample_t {
  int field1;
  std::mutex mtx;
};
```